# Difference between dependency properties in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

I have two implementations of dependency properties in WPF.
First, that I found in internet:

```
public class TestClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    private string _test;

    public string Test
    {
       get
       {
           return _test;
       }
       set
       {
           _test = value;
           OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Test))
       }
    }
}
```

And second, from *propdp* snippet:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public string Test
    {
         get { return (string)GetValue(TestProperty); }
         set { SetValue(TestProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TestProperty =     
        DependencyProperty.Register("Test", 
        typeof(string), 
        typeof(TestClass), 
        new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));
}
```

What is the difference between them? What should I use?

Comment: The first is not a dependency property. Read the [Dependency Properties Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914(v=vs.100).aspx) article on MSDN for all the details, especially for the differences to normal properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind to the `DependencyProperty` some value which can implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. For example, if you write:

```
<TextBox Content="{Binding FirstName}" />
```

then Content is a dependency property which will react to the binding source changing.

> The main difference is, that the value of a normal .NET property is
>   read directly from a private member in your class, whereas the value
>   of a DependencyProperty is resolved dynamically when calling the
>   GetValue() method that is inherited from DependencyObject.
>
> When you set a value of a dependency property it is not stored in a
>   field of your object, but in a dictionary of keys and values provided
>   by the base class DependencyObject. The key of an entry is the name of
>   the property and the value is the value you want to set.

[via](http://www.wpftutorial.net/dependencyproperties.html)

You should use simple properties in your ViewModels which you'll bind to the dependency properties in WPF objects (`Content`, `Background`, `IsChecked` and many other include DP which you will define in your custom user controls).

Comment: So, in my ViewModels I should use simple properties. But do I need OnPropertyChanged for them, like in first example? Do I understand right, that dependency property used only in your custom controls, like custom textbox, image etc.?

Comment: If you want to use data binding and have a reaction in your UI when property will changed then you need to implement INPC and raise ProprtyChanged event when value changed (like in your example). 
And yes dependency properties allow to use it in XAML syntax then there is no reason to use it in other scenarios.